# how to pass the smartcard info from one machine to another via ssh

Tags: ssh, smartcard

question:
I am logged into `machinA` with smartcard 
and using that smcartcard information I can ssh into the `machineB` by doing\

```
ssh -I pkcs11.so `machineB`
```

Now that I am in `machineB`, I want to use the smartcard info to login to `machineC`
But I am not able to do that.

I assume that it I have to pass some forwarding option when I come from ***machineA to machineB*** do: like so\

```
ssh -I pkcs11.so `machineB` -o "forwardagen=yes"
```

but I cannot figure out exactly which option will do that or if it is even possible!!

my goal is:
using smartcard information
I want to go from `machineA > machineB > machineC` \

please let me know if there is any option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting blog post describing an SSH tunnel for PC/SC: https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2022/02/one-smart-card-reader-accessible-from.html